# How do I use root to start Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I am attempting to use the root user as the cassandra user but getting an error in the output log:
Running Cassandra as root user or group is not recommended - please start Cassandra using a different system user.
If you really want to force running Cassandra as root, use -R command line option.

I understand what it is saying but I am not starting cassandra from the command line, I am using the "service dse start/stop" where do I add that -R

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! How are you "attempting to use the root user"? Your question is missing a few details. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) steps to replicate the problem. Cheers!

Comment: "I am using the `service dse start/stop`, where do I add that `-R`" -- in the corresponding systemd unit file, would be my guess.

Answer (score 1):

When running DSE as a service, the package installation automatically creates a service account on the server called `cassandra`. DSE uses this service account to run.

We do not recommend starting Cassandra as the `root` user for security reasons but if you really want to do it against recommendation, you will need to modify the `/etc/init.d/dse` script to add the `-R` option. Cheers!